# Open-Close Modal issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: popup, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal window (using bootstrap), with a close button. The modal window opens and closes fine in most browsers. However, in internet explorer, there is a problem.  We can open the modal window fine, and close it fine ... but if we try to open it again, it wont.

Most of the javascript functionality is in bootstrap. Below is the html for the open button [I believe  data-toggle="modal" and data-target="#exampleModal" are the key to opening the window]...

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="navdemo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Get The Demo</a>
```

...and the html for the start of the modal window, with the close button [note the id="exampleModal" tells which window to open. And the data-dismiss tells to close "modal"...

```
<div class="modal fade show" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" style="padding-right: 17px; display: block;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- CLOSE BUTTON -->
            <div class="row at-modal-close-box">
                <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <img src="https://www.amazingdg.com/_dev/temp/images/modal-close-btn.svg" alt="Close Demo Form">
                </a>
            </div>
    ...
```

You can view the page here:
https://www.amazingdg.com/_dev/temp/

Note: When I click the open button a second time, there is an error in IE's console ... Object.keys: argument is not an Object. Note: this error doesn't occur the first time opening the modal window. Not sure how to fix it...

### ---------------------------------------------------

I tried to remove the fade class ... that made the modal window show ALL of the hidden elements in the form (required fields, successfully sent message, etc.)

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
 $("#exampleModal").removeClass("fade");
}
```

### ---------------------------------------------------

I tried to change the fade transition (not supported by IE) using an IE media query. This removed the fade, but didn't fix the issue.

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) { /* IE10+ CSS styles go here */
    .fade {
        transition:none !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on IE, and it was solved by doing the following:

Whenever you open the modal, using:

```
modal.element.modal();
```

Send in an empty object, like this:

```
modal.element.modal({});
```

This fixed the issue for me in IE (without the need to mess with the fade classes) and didn't change the behavior in other browsers!

Comment: @Irf hit that up arrow then :)

Comment: Wonder, how I hadn't hit the one, it **is** deserved,

Answer (score 0):

Remove fade class which does not work in IE

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
 $("#exampleModal").removeClass("fade");
}
```

Comment: That looks like it doesn't remove the fade class, it adds a class called "ie"? Correct? Is that right?

Comment: Shouldn't it be...   if ($.browser.msie) {
 $("#exampleModal").removeClass("fade");
}

Comment: `removeClass` for remove class and `addClass` for adding

Comment: I have separate `ie` class so pasted my code quickly

Comment: Cool. I'll try it out.

Comment: The fade class does alot more than handle the fade. It completed blew up the form and started to show almost every hidden element.

If fade is a class ... maybe I can edit the style for a specific browser

Comment: See my post above, I changed the class details using a media query. This didn't affect the OPEN-CLOSE issue.

Comment: I saw in IE, that there is an error when the OPEN button is clicked a second time: Object.keys: argument is not an Object.  Check the link above and see if you get the error and have any idea how to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue that got a very simple fix.

You can simply toggle the modal using jQuery in the function that you call:

```
$("classnameORidName'").modal("show");
```