# Plus Minus Toggle on Clicking a Link

Tags: javascript, toggle

I have a link with a plus symbol (More Details[+]) ... when the user clicks the link, I want the link to change to a minus (More Details[-]), and show the content below it. I can show/hide the content, but the +/- toggle doesn't work. Note: I'm new to javascript, so please be patient with my lack of knowledge...

Note: There are a few posts about +/- toggles. I need help with the code that I wrote below.

Below is the javascript...

```
// Plus/Minus Toggle
function toggle_plus(id) {
    var f = document.getElementById(id);
    if (f.classList.contains("showplus")) {
            f.removeClass("showplus");
            f.addClass("showminus");
        } else {
            f.removeClass("showminus");
            f.addClass("showplus");
        }
}
// Toggle to show and hide content below the link
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block') {
      e.style.display = 'none';
   } else {
      e.style.display = 'block';
   }
}
```

And below is the html for the content.....

```
<div class="teamdetail">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('team4'); toggle_plus('team4Plus');">More Details [<span id="team4Plus" class="showplus"></span>]</a>
</div>
<div id="team4" class="teamtxt">
    Text Goes Here
</div>
```

And the CSS for the showplus and showminus

```
.showminus:before { content: '-'; } 
.showplus:before { content: '+'; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.removeClass` and `.addClass` are jQuery functions.  You need to use `.classList.add` and `.classList.remove`

```js
// Plus/Minus Toggle
function toggle_plus(id) {
    var f = document.getElementById(id);
    if (f.classList.contains("showplus")) {
            f.classList.remove("showplus");
            f.classList.add("showminus");
        } else {
            f.classList.remove("showminus");
            f.classList.add("showplus");
        }
}
// Toggle to show and hide content below the link
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block') {
      e.style.display = 'none';
   } else {
      e.style.display = 'block';
   }
}
```

```css
.showminus:before { content: '-'; } 
.showplus:before { content: '+'; }
```

```html
<div class="teamdetail">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('team4'); toggle_plus('team4Plus');">More Details [<span id="team4Plus" class="showplus"></span>]</a>
</div>
<div id="team4" class="teamtxt">
    Text Goes Here
</div>
```

Comment: You are awesome.

Comment: If you want to help with another issue...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49902103/open-close-modal-issue-in-internet-explorer    
Being hopeful.  :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Dave's answer (I don't have enough rep to comment :/), toggle is your friend.

```
// Plus/Minus Toggle
function toggle_plus(id) {
    var f = document.getElementById(id);
    f.classList.toggle("showplus");
    f.classList.toggle("showminus");
}
```

Will do the same.

Also, the Chrome inspector console is your friend - it would've been throwing up errors to you. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/