# Bootstrap Modal being temperamental

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

I am by no means a web developer but helped out at work with a webpage they needed doing and had been quoted a crazy price for.

The page is basically a list of sections represented by an image and when the image is clicked a modal opens which contains more information.

Some people have complained that the modals sometimes do not open, this is not limited to a particular one and people have said that they can open it, close it and then try opening it again but it does not work. This doesn't happen all the time though, sometimes there are no issues.

I have not been able to replicate this and I have tried several browsers. The users have all been using chrome or IE.

My code for the image for a section is,

```
<div class="col-xs-8 col-md-4 mb-3">
<div class="portfolio-item mx-auto" data-target="#ICUTI" data-toggle="modal">
<div class="portfolio-item-caption d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100 w-100">
<div class="portfolio-item-caption-content text-center text-white">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<img alt="urinary" class="img-fluid" src="https://www.website.org/getmedia/0e95e4ac-8285-44e5-999f-3f90abc15229/urinary" />
<p class="text-center">Urinary Tract Infections</p>
</div>
</div>
```

The code for the modal that opens when clicking this image is,

```
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="UrinaryTractLabel" class="portfolio-modal modal fade " id="ICUTI" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
<div class="modal-content"><button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-times">&nbsp;</i></span></button>

<div class="modal-body text-center">
<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div class="col-lg-12"><!-- Portfolio Modal - Title-->
<h2 class="portfolio-modal-title text-secondary text-uppercase mb-0" id="ICUrinaryTractLabel">Urinary Tract Infections</h2>

//the information held in the modal
```

When the modal is open there is a button at the bottom to close the modal,

```
<!--floating icon--><a class="float" href="#ICUrine"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up my-float">&nbsp;</i> </a><button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close Window</button></div>
```

Or an 'x' button in the top right

```
<div class="modal-content"><button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-times">&nbsp;</i></span></button>
```

Is there anything that anyone can see to suggest why sometimes a modal may not open? As I say, I have never been able to replicate this but people have said it happens occasionally?

Thanks

Comment: it might be browser support side, have you read the [Supported browsers by Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/browsers-devices/) ?? if not please take a look on it and also take a look at [BS4 browser bugs list](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/browser-bugs/) and maybe checking [Can i use for HTML5 and CSS](https://caniuse.com/?search=modal)

Comment: It looks like the browsers are supported. The people accessing the site are working in a hospital so all browsers should be up to date.

Comment: as per what you said that it is happens only for some not all of them, so it may depending on browser  support or you need to show us your JS code to determine how it can be fixed, also take alook at this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50024651/8134014)